# Making a linked list where each node is connected to another linked list.(java)

Tags: java, linked-list

I am creating a program that will read in a file, organize all of the words in lexicographic order, and output the word, how many times it appears in the document, and on what lines it appears. I have implemented this code in four different class files. However, I am having trouble linking the words to the linked list that will show the line numbers that the linked list arrives in. I am supposed to use the nodes of front and rear to traverse the list and am unsure how to go about iterating through this list and printing out each word.

here is the code form the class that take strings and make a linked list:

```
private class Node
        implements Entry<String, IntQueue> {
    String key;
    IntQueue queue = new IntQueue();
    Node link;

    Node(String keyword, Node newlink) {
        key = keyword;
        link = newlink;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public IntQueue getValue() {
        return queue;
    }

    public IntQueue setValue(IntQueue queue) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }


}

private Node head = new Node("", null);

public ListMap() {
    // Not needed, since head defaults to null anyway.
}

public void insert(String key, int linenr) {
    misc.trace("insert", key, linenr);
    Node prevcursor = head;
    Node cursor = head.link;
    boolean write = false;
    while (cursor != null) {

        if (key.compareTo(cursor.getKey()) < 0) {
            prevcursor.link = new Node(key, prevcursor.link);
            prevcursor.link.getValue().insert(linenr);
            write = true;
            break;
        }
        if (key.compareTo(cursor.getKey()) == 0) {
            cursor.queue.insert(linenr);
            write = true;
            break;
        }
        prevcursor = prevcursor.link;
        cursor = cursor.link;
    }
    if (!write) {
        prevcursor.link = new Node(key, prevcursor.link);
        prevcursor.link.getValue().insert(linenr);
    }
}
```

and here is the code that acually makes the int linked list:

```
  class IntQueue
            implements Iterable<Integer> {

        private class node {
            int linenr;
            node link;

            node(int number, node newlink) {
                linenr = number;
                link = newlink;
            }
        }

        private int count = 0;
        private node rear = null;
        private node front = new node(0, null);
        private int linenumb = 0;

       private int count = 0;
   private node rear = null;
   private node front = null;
   private int linenumb= 0;



     public void insert (int number) {
          ++count;
          misc.trace (count);
          if(front=null){
          node temp = new node(number,rear.link);
          front = temp;
          rear = temp;
          }else{
          if(linenumb != number ){
            rear.link= new node(number,null);
            }
          }
          linenumb = number;
          rear = rear.link;
       }
```

the big problem is the insert function in the second class. I can't understand how to link front and rear and to consistently add a new node every time the function is called in a way that can be called later

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you want help on. Is it specifically how to implement your intqueue.insert method? By the way the convention in Java is for all class names to start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: I totally agree with you but as this other kind commentator pointed out, this is indeed an assignment and I did not write these specific class names. My proffessor is an old school unix buff that would rather use underscores or all caps before he does caps

Comment: Next time, format your code before you post it. It helps both you and the people of SO.

Comment: You're tottally right, the lack of comments was really a mistake on my part after so long looking a single piece of code you don't feel you need it but you forget other people need to understand it. but i'm sure that's what you meant

Answer (score 0):

If your first issue is how to write the `insert` method for `IntQueue` then here are some suggestions. I'm assuming you don't want the code written as this looks like it's likely to be an assignment.

1. You are creating a new node as the `front` when the list is constructed. This is likely to be a mistake. The list is initially empty which is generally represented as `front` and `rear` being `null`.
2. The first thing to do in `insert` is to check if `front` is null. If it is you just set `front` and `rear` to a new node.
3. After that you know that `rear` will point to the most recently inserted node so you only need to check the new int to insert against `rear.lineNumber`.
4. Assuming you need a new node, create it, make `rear.link` point to it and then make `rear` point to it.

You're done.

As your assignment is a linked list with each node including a linked list I would expect your classes to be defined something like:

```
class WordList {
    private class Node {
        private String word;
        private int count;
        private LineNumberList lineNumbers;
        private Node next;
    }

    private Node head;
    private Node tail;

    public addWord(String word, int lineNumber) {
        ...
    }
}

class LineNumberList {
    private class Node {
        private int lineNumber;
        private Node next;
    }

    private Node head;
    private Node tail;

    public addLineNumber(int lineNumber) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Both `addWord` and `addLineNumber` should follow the same pattern as my algorithm above. However `addWord` will need to start by looking for the word and inserting it with a count of 1 if it's not present or incrementing the count if it is.

Comment: but front is not empty, it is the node that is linked to the linked list shown in listmap, this is my main problem is connecting front to the original linked list while also letting the list grow

Comment: Sorry that does not make a lot of sense. I would assume when you first create the list of line numbers it would be empty until you add the first one. You might need to post your data structure in a bit more detail.

Comment: I think im thinking about this the wrong way, how would I connect front to the next node in the linked list? do I set this when front is initially defined or would I do this in the loop that changes rear?

Comment: My algorithm in this answer does exactly that. Once the first item is created (step 2) both `front` and `rear` point to the new node. Then when the next node is inserted (step 4) `rear.link` points the new node. Because there's only one item in the list this means that `front.link` also points to that same node. Try it out and you'll see it works.

Comment: I am passed an integer, and I have been given the nodes front and rear to use in order to link the line numbers together. My specific assignment is to make a linked list of linked lists. your first response really helped with defining front and rear as the same node then changing rear but im having trouble linking front to anything.

Comment: Ah ok now I understand. You have two different linked lists. The code for the two will be very similar. I'll post some additional hints.

Comment: you are completely right on the structure of addWord and addNumber and I have already been able to calculate the total of how many times the word is present but the thing i am struggling with is the specific line numbers that the words are present on

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with? Knowing which line number you are reading in the file?

Comment: sorry I'm going to have to leave this until tomorrow - I'll check back and see if I can still help then. I'd appreciate it if you could vote my answer up at least after the help I've given so far :-)